# How to check overdispersion of binomial GLMMs, lme4 package

Tags: r, mixed-model, binomial-distribution, lme4-nlme, overdispersion

I have the following model

```
fit1 <- glmer(Res~FA+FB+FC+(1|fsite), family=binomial(), data=DATA)
```

the result of `summary()` is:

```
summary(fit1)
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood 
 (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: Res ~ FA + FB + FC + (1 | fsite)
   Data: DATA

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   202.3    229.9    -92.1    184.3      150 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.1768 -0.6167 -0.4967  0.6815  2.0132 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 fsite  (Intercept) 0        0       
Number of obs: 159, groups:  fsite, 28

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  1.55573    0.55830   2.787 0.005327 ** 
FA2         -0.11914    0.37344  -0.319 0.749692    
FB2         -1.38652    0.39967  -3.469 0.000522 ***
FC2         -0.14976    0.61984  -0.242 0.809076    
FC3         -0.06794    0.63171  -0.108 0.914350    
FC4         -1.20114    0.61670  -1.948 0.051452 .  
FC5         -1.44951    0.62817  -2.308 0.021025 *  
FC6         -1.13590    0.65427  -1.736 0.082538 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ?**?0.001 ?*?0.01 ??0.05 ??0.1 ??1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
        (Intr) fspcs2    FB2    FC2    FC3    FC4    FC5 
FA2     -0.466                                          
FB2     -0.456  0.169                                   
FC2     -0.572 -0.021  0.017                            
FC3     -0.596  0.050  0.036  0.506                     
FC4     -0.582 -0.005  0.020  0.519  0.509              
FC5     -0.558  0.019 -0.038  0.508  0.500  0.511       
FC6     -0.391 -0.101 -0.288  0.485  0.467  0.486  0.492
```

- Why are the variance and Std.Dev of the random effects zero?
- How do I check for overdispersion in this model?
- What should do if there is overdispersion?

Comment: What kind of numbers are there in `res`? Is it a vector of `1`a & `0`s, or is each entry a count of 'successes' out of multiple trials?

Comment: @RobertLong, note that the `[r]` tag provides syntax highlighting. That's 1 of the reasons I added it. I'm not sure if `[mixed-model]` adds much, given `[lme4]` & `[glmer]`. Maybe I'll try `[glmm]` for both `[mixed-model]` & `[glmer]`, & put `[r]` back for the syntax highlighting.

Comment: @gung ahh - OK I didn't know that, sorry. Personally I'd like to see a search of the [mixed-model] tag find a question like this so maybe one of [glmm] and [lme4] is redundant ? Hmmm

Comment: @RobertLong, I think Ben might prefer the [lme4] tag. I just switched [mm] for [glmm]. Hopefully, that will do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why are the variance and Std.Dev of the random effects zero?

Because the marginal variance among sites in your data is *less* than would be expected from a binomial variable; the variance can't be negative, so it's estimated as zero. The [GLMM FAQ](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html) discusses this.

> How do I check for overdispersion in this model?

This looks like a binary (not just binomial) regression, i.e. your responses are 0/1 (if you had "m out of N" responses where `N>1`, you either need a two-column response variable of (successes,failures), *or* you need to specify the `weights` argument). Therefore, overdispersion is not identifiable (e.g., see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/206007/can-there-be-overdispersion-in-a-logistic-regression-model-where-each-observatio) or [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/91597/overdispersion-in-logistic-regression)). **tl;dr**, you don't need to worry about it.  If you did have `N>1`, the previously linked GLMM FAQ gives some guidance ... the `overdisp_fun` from there can be used; depending on your philosophy of model-building you can use a hypothesis test (e.g. $p<0.05$?) or a rule of thumb (e.g. overdispersion factor > 1.1) to decide whether you should worry about it.

> What should do if there is overdispersion?

See previous answer (i.e., don't worry about if you have Bernoulli responses; otherwise, see the FAQ or elsewhere for strategies).

> What do I do if the data are unbalanced? (asked in comments)

Unless you have data that are *severely* unbalanced, or unless the data are structured that you have *complete separation* (all zeros or all ones for some combinations of predictor variables), GLMMs will handle unbalanced data fine; there's no need for manual adjustment.

Comment: Many tanks for the answer.

I am a little confused. In this example, the response variable is 0-1 data. Therefore, the overdispersion doesn't apply here. However, how do I deal with data with unequal number of zeors and ones? How can I evaluate the unequal? If the 80% vs 20% is unequal, how about 60% vs 40?

For proportional data, can I use the ‘overdisp_fun’ to test overdispersion? Can I say that there is overdispersion when ‘p’ value is smaller than 0.05?

Comment: @cww none of that has anything to do with over dispersion.